# Should I select features for imputation

Tags: r, machine-learning, correlation, data-imputation, mice

When imputing a missing value (in my case using MICE) -  should I use all the variables in the dataset or should I use only the variable which correlate most with the missing values I want to impute?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you expand to give more details and also clarify what you mean by "correlate most with the missing values"?

Comment: I mean those variables who have low Pearson R or low score in a heatmap. In my case (working with a dataset of train passengers) I have missing values in "Age" variable, and I know that "Ticket Number" each passenger got is a random number, thus have nothing to do with age, but I fear the machine can take it as a correlation.